# Unable to generate selected data details in tab created using shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have started practicing shiny package for making dashboard, and i am still an amateur at R, please help me to display the data which will be selected using selectinput  in the allocated tab which i have created for display of data.

I shall share my ui code as well as server code. Please assist how to display selected data in the data tab created.

ui.R code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel(h1("Test for application of all the tutorials completed till now")),


  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel((h2("Information Panel Enter")),


                 selectInput("data", "Select the dataset for hist analysis", 

                             choices = c("iris","pressure","USArrests", selected = "pressure")),


                 numericInput("obs", "Select the number of observations for the dataset", value = 5,min = 5,max = 30,step = 1 ),


                 sliderInput("bins", "Select the number of bins for histogram", value = 6, min = 6, max = 20, step = 1),


                 radioButtons("color", "selecct the color of histogram" , choices = c("black","purple","brown"))),



    mainPanel((h3("Main Panel of all the information display")),

              tabsetPanel(type = c("pills"),

                          tabPanel("Summary" , h4(textOutput("Mysumhead")) ,verbatimTextOutput("Mysum")),

                          tabPanel("Structure and Observation" , h4(textOutput("Mystrhead")), verbatimTextOutput("Mystr")),

                          tabPanel("Plot"),

                          tabPanel("Data" , verbatimTextOutput("Mydata"))))

)))
```

server.R code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(datasets)

shinyServer(function(input,output){


  output$Mysum <- renderPrint({

    summary(get(input$data))

  })


  output$Mysumhead <- renderText({

    paste("Data Selected for checking summary is " , input$data)

  })


  output$Mystr <- renderPrint({


    str(get(input$data))


  })

  output$Mystrhead <- renderText({

    paste("Data selected for observing summary of the data is " , input$data)

  })


  output$Mydata <- renderTable({

      data(input$data) 


  })



})
```

Answer (score 0):

you are good in all point except one.

In the UI.R, in Data TAB just change to `tableOutput("Mydata")` and in Server.R change the code inside `rendertable({})` change it to  `get(input$data)`.

It will be good to go. You should use tableOutput for displaying Table when you want to use renderTable in server side

Comment: Thank You Mr Subhasish 1315, it worked, worked perfectly as i wanted it to come :)